# Altering wordpress featured image visibility on home page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is probably an overly simple question, but I have a blog [Creating Wealth From Birth](http://www.creating-wealth-from-birth.com/) that I have recently set up with Wordpress.org.  I've installed a Woothemes template which has an option to set a featured image for a post, very much regular.  However, I would like to remove the featured image on the homepage feed because it rests on top of the post title and is not the correct resolution.

I would like to keep the featured image everywhere but the homepage feed, but I'm not sure if or where to go into the php files to modify this.  Is there any rule of thumb how to change this, or what file it might be titled under?

Thanks so much, and if there is any other information that you require from me let me know.

Alexi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexi,

I'm not sure how experienced you are with PHP or Wordpress modification so let me know if you need more assistance. You should go into the Appearance -> Editor section in Wordpress and look for the Header or Main Index Template file (however your theme works). Within there should be the PHP code that determines what logo, if any, you set in your WooThemes options. You should just remove or comment out that section, and set up the logo under your own styling. Maybe create a "div" and use "img src" to display your image within it. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thank's so much, I found it in the main index.php file through the editor. :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you out!